# Databinding with Resource go to wrong

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I custom cardView from Framlayout and binding to text in xml:

```
 <****ValueCardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            bind:text="@{@string/about_mail_title}">
```

But It have error:

```
Error:(54) No resource identifier found for attribute 'text' in package ****
Error:(16, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@{@string/about_mail_title}').
```

I don't understand my wrong.

Comment: `CardView` doesn't contain text method, what are you trying to do? What is type of your `ValueCardView` ?

Comment: Yes, But it is databinding. I have function get, set in ValueCardView ( ValueCardView extends from FrameLayout)